# POSTGRESQL - Polygon function for geolocations

Tags: sql, postgresql, geolocation, polygon

I have 2 tables User_places where I can see for each user their home location defined by 2 separate attributes: longitude and latitude.
And I have second table Neighborhoods with attribute 'Area', that defines each neighborhood as polygon - jsonb format - "[{"latitude":XXXXX,"longitude":YYYYY},{"latitude":ZZZZZ,"longitude":AAAAA},{"latitude":BBBBBB,"longitude":CCCCC},{"latitude":DDDDD,"longitude":EEEEE}]".

Does anybody know how to check whether particular user lives in given neighborhood in Postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
user_id,
ST_Contains(
ST_GeomFromText(
   (select 
   replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(area::text,']','))'),'[','POLYGON(('),'}',  ''),',"longitude":',' '),'{"latitude":','')
   from neighbourhoods
   limit 1), 4326)
   (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(latitude, longitude),4326))
) as polygon_check
from user_places
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you have [Postgis](http://postgis.net/) installed on your copy of postgresql? As this has all the Geometry and geographical function extensions to postgresql.

You could use [ST_Contains](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html) to check if a point is contained in a given polygon, this returns a boolean.

```
select ST_Contains(neigbourhood.polygon,User_place.geom)
```

If you don't have a geom point value in the User_places table then this can be created using the [ST_SetSRID](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) function and [ST_MakePoint](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) function.

For example - `SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(LAT, LON),SRID);`

where SRID is the reference for the projection you are using for example 4326 for WGS 84 `

I would recommend in postgresql make sure all of your Geographical tables have geoms in them, as it makes comparisons much easier.

For reference a good place to get answers for geographic and geometry database based questions is https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have tried this code but it doesn't work. Can you see the problem? 'SELECT

ST_Contains(
 (SELECT area FROM neighbourhoods limit 1),
 (SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(latitude, longitude),4326) from user_places where user_id = 30840 )
)

from user_places'

Comment: ERROR: function st_contains(json, geometry) does not exist - can it be because of json format of polygon attribute 'area'?

Comment: You need to convert the json to a geometry, I use the ST_GeomFromGeoJSON function - postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html

Comment: yes Peter, I used ugly way to get data in right format but it worked. In the end "The ends justify the means". Thanks a lot for your help!